# I don't know why the "x" comes out

Tags: r

```
card2<-read.table("card.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE,skip=2,nrow=10)
```

```
> card2
   queen spades X12
1   jack spades  11
2    ten spades  10
3   nine spades   9
4  eight spades   8
```

In the origin file, there is no "X". but after I read the table, "X" is comes out in the RStudio
at the first row.
How can I remove it? And I want to know why the "X" is coming out.

Comment: Set `header=FALSE` or skip fewer rows.

Comment: Thank you. but i want to know why the "X" is appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, as Konrad pointed out, you are erroneously setting the first entry of your dataset as colnames(). Second, R doesn't allow numeric colnames, so it is appending an 'X' before the 12.

Comment: R *does* actually allow numeric column names, just not by default. Passing `check.names = FALSE` prevents the `X` from being added.

Comment: Thank you so much. I completely understand why it happened and how can i fix it.